# keep link style when changing page Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, styles

im using Smarty and php4(cant upgrade =( ).On my site on the left, i have a navigation-column with all my links. I want the link which i click to change color to RED and STAY RED until i click another link. I already found something when googling but i cant get it to work tough everyone says it runs perfectly :/..... the script changes the color to red when i click on a link but fails to keep the color RED after my url changes.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
// first component: non-active link-color
// second component: active link-color
var arrColor = new Array("#404040","#e40624");

var lnkOldID = "";
var lnkOldColor;

// get object-type
IE = document.all&&!window.opera;
DOM = document.getElementById&&!IE;


function activeLink(lnkID){
    // declare object
    myObj = (IE)?document.all[lnkID]:document.getElementById(lnkID);
    // if no link is chosen
    if(lnkOldID == ""){
        lnkOldID = lnkID;  // remember cur. ID 
        lnkOldColor = arrColor[0];  // remember cur. color
        myObj.style.color = arrColor[1];  // change color
    }else{
        // if current link is not active link
        if(lnkOldID != lnkID){
            // declare object
            var myOldObj = (IE)?document.all[lnkOldID]:document.getElementById(lnkOldID);
            myOldObj.style.color = lnkOldColor;    // set color to non-activelink color
            myObj.style.color = arrColor[1];      // setcolor to activelinkcolor 
            lnkOldID = lnkID;      // remember cur. ID 
            lnkOldColor = arrColor[0];  // remember cur. color
        }
    }
}
</script>
{/literal}

<a onClick="activeLink('verteilung_prios')" id="verteilung_prios" href="?n=navigation_pm&a=verteilung_prios">Verteilung Prios</a>
<a onClick="activeLink('histogramm_reaktionszeiten')" id="histogramm_reaktionszeiten" href="?n=navigation_pm&a=histogramm_reaktionszeiten">Histogramm Reaktionszeiten</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing class?

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/FWAYW/8/)

script :

```
function toggleColor(obj) {
    var redObjs = document.getElementsByClassName('red');

    for ( var i = 0; i < redObjs.length; i++ ) {
        redObjs[i].className = '';
    }

    obj.className = 'red';
}
```

add class function when page refresh
execute in document.onload

```
function initClass() {
    // get now url
    //var nowUrl = document.location.href;
    // dummy url
    var nowUrl = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/now/';

    // get elements that have 'navi' class
    var naviObjs = document.getElementsByClassName('navi');

    for ( var i = 0; i < naviObjs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( naviObjs[i].href == nowUrl ) {
            // check url
            //alert(naviObjs[i].className);

            // add 'red' class
            naviObjs[i].className += ' red';
        }
    }
}
```

css :

```
a:visited
{
    color: #404040;
}

a.red
{
    color: #e40624;
}
```

Comment: thx for help, but same problem as before. when url changes the style  resets

Comment: Can you set class to now url tag by Smarty? like this <a class="{$classValue}">